# codeigniter sub-domain redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

Hi I have a website hosted on lkn.ccomsys.net and is written using codeigniter framework. However only my index page seems to open whereas none of the inner pages open. Below is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /lkn
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.


  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have checked all possible solutions given on stack overflow by adding a / before index.php in rewrite rule + adding a . before the same + making my rewrite base to lkn.ccomsys.net. However none of these solutions seems to work. Could I please get some help on the same.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /root_folder_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is still not working. Only the home page seems to open.

Comment: Change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to ` `$config['index_page'] = '';` in  `application\config\config.php`

Comment: It is already set to ' '. My main site folder is however outside the public_html folder. Is there any change in the .htaccess rules then?

Comment: Either your Home works or it doesn't! "Seems to open" means you are not sure. Have you relocated your application and system folders above your public_html folder ( which is a good idea )?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw My home page is working. The inner pages shows a 404 error. I have a folder(Lets call it 'A') placed outside my public_html folder and have both the application and system folder's inside the same(Folder 'A'). My sub-domain created has its root folder pointed to the folder that I have created outside my public_html folder (folder 'A').